# Sequence converges to a single value.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If it is given than a sequence converges to a single value then we can write this as say $(a_n)\rightarrow a $ where $a$ is the limit of the sequence $a_n$. 
If we suppose also that the same sequence $(a_n)\rightarrow b $, how can we reach a contradiction (assuming $a<b$)? 
We are using the definition that if $b_n)\rightarrow \ell $ then $\exists N\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $\forall n>N, |b_n-\ell | <\epsilon , \forall \epsilon >0 $. 
I'm just not quite sure how to prove this result (that a sequence, if it converges, converges to a single value.

Comment: A simple way to show this is to use the Haudorffness of $\mathbb{R}$: If $a,b$ are distinct, they have disjoint open neighbourhoods $U \ni a, V \ni b$. Then $(a_n)$ is either eventually in $U$ or eventually in $V$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
|a-b|=|a-a_n+a_n-b|\le|a-a_n|+|a_n-b|
$$

Comment: This says $|a-b|\leq 2\epsilon $?

Comment: @Ben Yes. We have that $|a-b|\le\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. If we suppose that $|a-b|=c>0$, we get a contradiction by choosing $\varepsilon=c/2$.

Comment: So this implies a=b then. Are there any other way of proving this result that are simple?

Comment: I don't know a simpler way to prove this. Which part seems complicated?

Comment: This is very simple and I do understand it. I was just seeing if there were alternative methods.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $\epsilon=\frac12(b-a)$. Is it possible to have $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ **and** $|a_n-b|<\epsilon$?

Comment: How does choosing $epsilon =\frac{1}{2} (b-a) $ show that we cannot have $|a_n-a|<\epsilon \textbf{ and } |a_n-b| < \epsilon $?

Comment: @Ben: Because $a$ and $b$ are $2\epsilon$ units apart, so nothing can be less than $\epsilon$ units away from both. The point $a+\epsilon=b-\epsilon$ is the midpoint of the interval $[a,b]$, and it’s $\epsilon$ units away from $a$ and from $b$; if you move it closer to one of $a$ and $b$, you move it further away from the other, so you can never get it to be less than $\epsilon$ from both simultaneously. (It’s  really just an instance of the triangle inequality, but the explanation that I just gave seems a little more intuitive.)

Comment: Is there are more formal, mathematical wa to write this or is it best just explaining this in words in a proof?

Comment: @Ben: Just use the triangle inequality: if $n$ is large enough so that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ and $|a_n-b|<\epsilon$, then $$\epsilon=b-a=|a-b| =|a-a_n+a_n-b|\le |a-a_n|+|a_n-b|<\frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2=\epsilon\;,$$ which is absurd.